# If $f \to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ then $1/f \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I want to show that if $f:(0,\infty)$ is a function such that $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0$, then $1/f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

I'll need to use the epsilon-delta definition of a limit to do this.

I'm wondering whether the following statement is correct:

The above for $f(x)$ is equivalent to saying that $\forall M >0\space \exists N>0$ such that $x > N \implies f(x) > M \space\forall\space x \in (0,\infty)$

If it is correct, how do I get from here to my conclusion about $1/f(x)$?

Comment: First write down the *definition* of $\frac 1{f(x)} \to 0$. You have to insert some things that this definition gives, into the statement involving $f(x) \to \infty$. In particular, remember that $f(x) > M$ implies $\frac 1{f(x)} < \frac 1M$.

Comment: So I need that $1/f(x) < M \forall x > N$?

Comment: Right. If you let me guide you then you will get it. Write down the definition of $\frac 1{f(x)} \to 0$. (We want to prove this)

Comment: This is: $\forall M>0 \exists N>0$ such that $x>N \implies 1/f(x)<M \space \forall x$. Right?

Comment: Excellent. So have to show for *each* $M$, there is an $N$ such that some condition holds. Now, write down the definition of $f(x) \to \infty$, which you know is *true*.

Comment: $\forall C>0 \exists D>0$ such that $x>D \implies f(x)>C \space \forall x$

Comment: Oh I let $M = 1/C$?

Comment: ALMOST THERE. That substitution is almost right, it is $C = \frac 1M$. (They are the same : but you are *given* $M$. You set $C = \frac 1M$ , get the $N$ from the definition of $f(x) \to \infty$, and see that this same $N$ works for the definition $\frac 1{f(x)} \to 0$).

Comment: Ah yes, because we have to go from the given statement to the new one, as opposed to the other way around?

Comment: Yes, you are right, and a quick learner. I shall up vote for your eagerness. Now, I wish to write an answer, and you can dictate the format to me. Tell me how you want it, I tailor it to those wishes, senor. Scratch that, there's an answer!

Comment: For all of the above, should $x<N$ or $x>N$?

Comment: $x>N$ is the right choice.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  you're a really good teacher. Upvoted your latest comment.

Comment: $\frac1{f(x)}<\frac1M$, maybe ?

Comment: @Pritam Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Your advice was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that since the domain of $f$ is $(0, \infty)$, the limit must be as $x \to 0^+$.  Your given information is that $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$, which means:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\forall M \exists \delta > 0 \forall x(0 < x < \delta \Rightarrow f(x) > M).
\end{equation}
What you have to prove is that $1/f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$, which means:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x(0 < x < \delta \Rightarrow |1/f(x)| < \epsilon).
\end{equation}

Hints for the proof:  First look at your goal (2).  The form of that statement suggests that you should start with "Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive number," and then you should try to come up with a good choice for $\delta$.  The form of (1) suggests that to use it, you should come up with something to plug in for $M$.  (1) says that no matter what number you plug in for $M$, there will be a corresponding $\delta$ with a certain property.

Comment: Should it not be $x>\delta$?

Comment: Nope... it's always $x<\delta$..

Comment: Because see the definition for the limit when $x\to 0^+$ says that for all $x \in (0,\delta)$ the functional value should be greater than the pre assigned positive number

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall M:\exists\,\delta > 0:\forall\,|x|< \delta :f(x) > M$$

is equivalent to

$$\forall M:\exists\,\delta > 0:\forall\,|x|< \delta :\frac1{f(x)}<\frac1M$$

and to

$$\forall\epsilon:\exists\,\delta > 0:\forall\,|x|< \delta :\frac1{f(x)}<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given.

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$, for every $N\gt 0$ there exists $\delta\gt 0$ such that $f(x)\gt N$ if $x\lt\delta$.

By the Archimedean ordering of the real numbers, given $\epsilon\gt 0$, we can find $N$ such that $N\epsilon\gt 1\implies \frac{1}{N}\lt\epsilon$.

Then $x\lt\delta\implies f(x)> N\implies\frac{1}{f(x)}\lt\frac{1}{N}\lt\epsilon$

Therefore, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{f(x)}=0$